# Is is possible to apply a Group Policy for the same user logged-on to different computers?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a user (say, `domain.local\admin`) in my domain.

- When he logons to `vpn.domain.local` in group `Servers` I want to apply a policy.
- When he logons to `laptop.domain.local` in group `Destop Computers` I want either do not apply this policy or apply the same with opposite value.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by applying the `opposite` policy, but it sounds like what you want to do is to apply a different set of User Configuration settings when this user logs onto a particular computer. If that's the case then you need to look into Group Policy loopback policy processing, which would allow you to do just that.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback.aspx

Comment: Yes. I want to apply different windows explorer settings (hide something - turn on) for the the same user on one computer, and on another computer - the opposite (side something - turn off). I think you got it. Will check out your link right away. Thanks!

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. I have a policy object for Authd Users and Group "Desktop Computers" which sets particular policy off. And another object for Authd Users and Group "Servers" which sets the same policy on. I run gpupdate and logoff/login. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. Are you trying to configure a User Configuration setting or a Computer Configuration setting?

Comment: User Configuration -> Policies -> Admin Templates, I modify a policy somewhere inside. Also I turned on Loopback mode. Now I expect when user logges-on to a computer in group "Servers" the appropriate object will be applied to his windows explorer settings. Incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You have two computers. We'll call them `A` and `B`. You also need two different Organization Units. We'll call them `X` and `Y`. Finally, you need two different polices. We'll call them `J` and `K`.

To make this work, apply policy `J` to *computers* (not users) in OU `X`, and policy `K` to computers in OU `Y`. Put computer `A` in OU `X` and computer `B` in OU `Y`. Now edit your polies and use [Item Level Targeting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIt_dPTD0os&noredirect=1) to limit the policy to only apply when the desired user is logged in, or when a user with a targeted Active Directory group is logged in.

Comment: It seems Item Level Targeting can be applied for user Preferences but I need to apply it to user Policies. And I don't see ILT in policy settings, only not set, on, off.

Comment: ILT can apply to any policy object, but it applies to the whole policy object, and not individual settings within the object.

Comment: [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022.aspx) says ITL can be applied to Preferences under Computer Configuration or User Configuration. Not Policies.